# Certain order of fields in content-disposition with jersey-client

Tags: java, jax-rs, multipart, content-disposition, jersey-client

I'm using jersey-client to send post requests with multipart/form-data. Third-party server uses very old version of com.oreilly.servlet.multipart (COS) to parse it, and the problem here is [how COS extracts information about content-disposition](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.servlets/cos/05Nov2002/com/oreilly/servlet/multipart/MultipartParser.java#MultipartParser.extractDispositionInfo%28java.lang.String%29). In a nutshell: it can't parse filename field if it goes before name field.
So, it leads to inability to send file parts with jersey-client, because it places name field at the end of content-disposition (and I really believe it's ok, because according to RFC order of fields in content-disposition shouldn't matter), filename isn't parsed and without filename this third-party server doesn't recognize this part as file.
And the question is: how to set content-disposition for FileDataBodyPart preserving order of fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked source code of FormDataContentDisposition class and found that it constructs content-disposition in certain order

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(type);
addStringParameter(sb, "filename", fileName);
addDateParameter(sb, "creation-date", creationDate);
addDateParameter(sb, "modification-date", modificationDate);
addDateParameter(sb, "read-date", readDate);
addLongParameter(sb, "size", size);
return sb;
```

So, workaround for this problem is to extend from this class and override this method.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a workaround:

```
    StreamDataBodyPart filePart = new StreamDataBodyPart("File.docx", is) {
        @Override
        protected FormDataContentDisposition buildContentDisposition() {
            FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition = new FormDataContentDisposition("form-data", getName(), getName(), null, null, null, 0) {
                @Override
                protected StringBuilder toStringBuffer() {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(this.getType());
                    addStringParameter(sb, "name", getName());
                    addStringParameter(sb, "filename", getName());
                    return sb;
                }
            };
            return contentDisposition;
        }
    };
```